# Sum of time statuses

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simplified version of the table with information about the status of an instrument.  I am trying to find the total time from each status.  The DateAdded is a timestamp indicating the beginning of the status and the next entry would be the end of the first status and beginning of the next status.

```
+--------------------+-----------+-------------------------+
| InstrumentStatusId | Statename |        DateAdded        |
+--------------------+-----------+-------------------------+
|             737062 | alarming  | 2018-03-14 00:37:51.423 |
|             737064 | running   | 2018-03-14 00:38:12.410 |
|             737065 | running   | 2018-03-14 00:38:21.443 |
|             737149 | alarming  | 2018-03-14 01:45:03.433 |
|             737152 | error     | 2018-03-14 01:45:39.443 |
|             737153 | idle      | 2018-03-14 01:45:42.457 |
|             737154 | running   | 2018-03-14 01:45:42.460 |
|             737155 | idle      | 2018-03-14 01:45:45.490 |
|             737356 | running   | 2018-03-14 04:20:21.350 |
|             737382 | idle      | 2018-03-14 04:36:03.433 |
|             737383 | running   | 2018-03-14 04:36:03.437 |
|             737384 | idle      | 2018-03-14 04:36:06.463 |
|             737890 | running   | 2018-03-14 10:13:00.313 |
|             738201 | alarming  | 2018-03-14 11:10:41.120 |
|             738204 | idle      | 2018-03-14 11:11:11.120 |
|
+--------------------+-----------+-------------------------+
```

I am having trouble figuring out a solution that takes into account multiple same statuses and calculating the time difference between statuses. I have seen similar questions but can't find a solution that has helped me.

I have a [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ada0f) to play with the data.

Comment: how do you identify which rows are the same status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer interprets "status" as being synonymous with `statename`.

I think you just need the first record for each status.  To get that, use `lag()`, then `lead()` on the result, then aggregation:

```
select statename,
       sum(datediff(second, dateadded, next_dateadded)) as total_seconds
from (select s.*,
             lead(dateadded) over (order by dateadded) as next_dateadded
      from (select s.*, lag(statename) over (order by dateadded) as prev_statename
            from instrumentstatus s
           ) s
      where prev_statename is null or prev_statename <> statename
     ) s
group by statename;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/38b39/1) is a SQL Fiddle.